# Draw bitmap on window in wpf

Tags: wpf, bitmapimage, drawimage

I'm new in WPF.

I have implemented code in mfc which load the bitmap and draw it some portion on window
now want to port the similar functionality in WPF.

I want to draw bitmap on my WPF window and do some operation. window will not have min, max, close button.

below is my mfc code.

```
LRESULT Mywindow::OnPaint(UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM, BOOL&)
        {
            CPaintDC dc(this);
        CDC cdc;
        HDC hdc = dc.GetSafeHdc();
        cdc.Attach(hdc);
        paintBitmapOnWindow(&cdc);
        }

    void Mywindow::paintBitmapOnWindow(CDC* pCdc)
    {
         HBITMAP backgroundBitmap;
        backgroundBitmap = (HBITMAP)::LoadImage(0, _T("C:\\temp.bmp"), IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
        CDC cdcCompatible;
        cdcCompatible.CreateCompatibleDC(pCdc);
        cdcCompatible.SelectObject(backgroundBitmap);

        CRect clientRect;
        GetClientRect(clientRect);

        int clientHalfWidth = 800 / 2;
        CRect clientLeft;
        CRect imageLeft;
        BITMAP bm;
        ::GetObject(backgroundBitmap, sizeof(BITMAP), (PSTR)&bm);

        clientLeft.SetRect(clientRect.left, clientRect.top, clientRect.left + clientHalfWidth, clientRect.bottom);

        int bitmapHalfWidth = bm.bmWidth / 2;
        int bitmapLeftOffset = bitmapHalfWidth - 0;

        imageLeft.SetRect(bitmapLeftOffset - clientLeft.Width(), 0, bitmapLeftOffset, bm.bmHeight);

        pCdc->StretchBlt(clientLeft.left, clientLeft.top, clientLeft.Width(), clientLeft.Height(), &cdcCompatible,
            imageLeft.left, imageLeft.top, imageLeft.Width(), imageLeft.Height(), SRCCOPY);
        cdcCompatible.DeleteDC();
    }
```

what are the similar function/class which i can use to convert it into WPF?

Comment: It is strongly recommended that you use WPF's built in [Vector Graphics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747393(v=vs.110).aspx) capabilities as opposed to bitmaps. Bitmaps don't scale well and you might end up with a highly pixelated UI in large screen resolutions, whereas vector graphics scale endlessly without losing quality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to blit the bitmap directly to the window, and you wish to directly control the rendering you may simply override the OnRender function.  However there is on catch  (noted in the comments of the code)...

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Background = Brushes.Transparent;  // <-- necessary  (strange bug)
        // Charles Petzold writes about this at the following link:
        // http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/750e91c2-c370-4f0a-b18e-892afd99bd9b/drawing-in-onrender-beginnerquestion?forum=wpf
    }

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        base.OnRender(drawingContext);
        BitmapSource bitmapSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("C:\\Temp.png", UriKind.Absolute));
        CroppedBitmap croppedBitmap = new CroppedBitmap(bitmapSource, new Int32Rect(20, 20, 100, 100));
        drawingContext.DrawImage(croppedBitmap, new Rect(0.0d, 0.0d, this.RenderSize.Width / 2.0d, this.RenderSize.Height));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, its working but i want to draw some part of image instead of complete image, similar to StretchBlt() method of MFC in which we can specify image rectangle as well.

Comment: @user3106005 - I updated the code to render only a portion of the image.  Hope this helps.